# Why this print in a file adds newline I didn't ask for?

Tags: python, python-3.x

So, until now I've been using Python 2 and to write arrays in a file I used

```
with open('File.txt', 'w') as f:
    for item in File:
        print >> f, item
```

and this worked perfectly fine.

Now I've switched to Python 3 and that code doesn't work anymore, so I switched to

```
with open('File.txt', 'w') as f:
    for item in File:
        f.write(f'{item}')
```

Thing is however, I don't get output in a format as I expected.

The object I'm printing is an array with lots of values inside and I want them to be displayed one for each line.

While with the above Python3 code I get:

```
[0.00034041 0.00037384 0.00041032 0.00045011 0.00049349 0.00054075
 0.00059222 0.00064822 0.00070912 0.00077532 0.00084723 0.00092529
```

I want instead

```
0.00034041 
0.00037384 
0.00041032 
0.00045011 
0.00049349 
0.00054075
0.00059222
```

Can you explain what is missing and why does it behave like this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could add a newline `'\n'` for each item:

```
with open('File.txt', 'w') as f:
    for item in File:
        f.write(f'{item}\n')
```

If item is an `np.array`, you could try this:

```
#Create the variable File with np.arrays of shape (1,341)

arr = np.array(np.arange(341)).reshape(1,341)
print('item.shape:',arr.shape)
File=[]
for i in range(5):
        File.append(arr)
        
with open('File.txt', 'w') as f:
    for item in File:
        for val in item[0]:
            f.write(f'{val}\n')
```

Comment: That depends on the content of `item` in his program.

Comment: already tried that but it doesn't work. F1 is a np.array whose shape is (1, 341)

Comment: Oh ok, just as @jpandas said. In that case you have to iterate with to for loops. I'will edit my answer.

Answer (score -4):

After some more testing I've found out what the problem was.

It just need indxexing to access the values in the proper way.

I'll post the answer so it can be helpful to other who may bump in the same trouble.

```
with open('FILE.txt', 'w') as f:
    for item in FILE[0]:
        f.write(f'{item}\n')
```

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62514358/5211833), in particular the second solution, is *exactly* the same. This therefor borders on plagiarism in my opnion, and is highly impolite towards the other answerer, whose answer you should've accepted instead.

Comment: Most likely the complete solution was not there when I added mine so no need to be offending me of plagiarism. Why would I add mine if others solution already worked?

Comment: The other answer is from June 22nd. Yours is from June 27th. Would you like to reconsider your position ("Most likely the complete solution was not there when I added mine")? Or maybe you want to highlight the differences and elaborate why you prefer this different solution. Actually you accepted the other answer as "most helpful". To me that seems to be some kind of conflict...

Comment: @Adriaan hello, it I checked and it seems I didn't see the second solution after it was edited unfortunately. I accepted that as answer. Please remove all the down votes...I apologize, but no need to have this toxic behavior towards newcomers

Comment: The other answer was edited on June 22nd, the same day it was created and 4-5 days before yours was created, you have enough experience/reputation to at least use the available information. If you want downvotes removed you will have to [edit] and improve your answer or at least avoid the impression Adriaan has described. But even if you edits impress Adriaan, they can only undo the at most one downvote they did themselves. It seems however, that your answer has disappointed at 3 others, 2 who also downvoted, one more who downvoted if not Adriaan - and me. Consider elaborating the new insight.

Comment: please ignore this solution. Correct answer was already posted, which I didn't see cause it was edited later. I already apologised. It was not my intention to copy someone else's answer. What would be the point of doing such thing while I'm still learning? As I said it was just oversight by me (which I apologised because I'm new to the website and the edit didn't catch my eye). With your downvotes now I'm blocked from posting any other question so far. Thank you I guess